# Why can't I manipulate a list items using for in loop? (Python)

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

Why does this code work as intended (manipulate the list elements):

```
numbers = [42, 123]
numbers[1] = 5

for index in range(len(numbers)):
      print(numbers[index]) 
      numbers[index] = numbers[index] * 2
      print(numbers[index])
print(numbers)
```

```
Output:
84
10
[84, 10]
```

While this code doesn't:

```
for number in numbers:
    number = number * 2
    print(number)
print(numbers)
```

```
Output:
84
10
[42, 5]
```

My initial thought is that the for in loop creates a scoped variable `number` that is equal to the value of `numbers[i]` and that variable is what gets manipulated and not the list. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Reassigning `number` does not reassign the list index that it originally came from.  They’re independent references to the same value (until you reassign one of them, at which point they’re references to different values).

Answer (score 1):

In the 2nd block of code it is not modifying the elements of the list, it is only modifying the local variable `number`.

You can use something like `enumerate()` to loop over the elements and indicies at once:

```
for i, number in enumerate(numbers):
  numbers[i] = number * 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manipulating an existing list, build a new list based on the old one using a *list comprehension*.
Then assign `numbers` to point to that new list.

```
numbers = [42, 5]
numbers = [2*n for n in numbers]
```

A couple of things to note here:

- This code is much less complicated.
- For a large list, a comprehension will be significantly faster.
- Variables in Python are basically references to objects. So when you re-assign `numbers`, the list `[42,5]` loses a reference. If it is not referenced elsewhere, it will be garbage-collected.